# REST services for HyperLedger Fabric JAVA Chaincode

Tags: java, rest, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am very new to blockchain development and I come to know about hyper ledger fabric for permission blockchains.

My task is to create a simple blockchain application using hyper ledger fabric platform.

I want to use the Java SDK for development of Chaincode. Here I could run a sample also and queried the network using the command line tool.

I don't know exactly how to clients ( for example Android mobile application ) will communicate with the blockchain. We should have web service ( API ) so that any client application can communicate with the blockchain (Android, iPhone, AngularJS ).

I am able to create REST Services using hyper ledger composer, but I found that, for development purposes, the composer is not feasible.

I have the following questions,

1 ) How can I create REST services for my Hyperledger Fabric Network ( Chaincode should be in Java Language)?

2 ) Is it true that Hyperledger Composer is not reliable for the long run?

Thank,

Comment: You could write a small spring boot app with REST and hook that up to hyperledger chain.

Answer (score 1):

1) Chaincode can be on Java language, no problem with that. For the API Rest you can use the Java SDK to call the chaincode and receive the calls from the clients.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-java

So you are going to end up having an API Rest that uses the fabric sdk to call to the chaincode. This API is going to be executed outside of the blockchain, and the chaincode with java that is going to receive the calls from the API and is going to be executed on the blockchain.

Here you have a tutorial on how to use the fabric SDK

https://codeburst.io/a-concise-tutorial-on-working-with-hyperledger-fabric-java-sdk-a6f11d8bb5b0

2)This is just my opinion, Composer is good for quick POC, but thats it. It has its limitations and is not as flexible as doing it on hyperledger fabric.

Comment: but how can I expose rest services? So that I can access the blockchain from the outside world? example, in Composer we have composer-rest-server, who generates rest services for us

Comment: In this case you should create it. For example, create a normal SpringBoot api and then use the Fabric SDK to call the blockchain services. I will put on the answer a link to a tutorial.